# How can I find carrots and potatoes in an older (pre-vegetable) minecraft world seed

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So have been running an older version of Minecraft for a while, which was before the update with carrots and potatoes.  Now that I have updated to the latest version of the game, I was wondering how carrots and potatoes will spawn in the map.  Will I be able to find them anywhere, or only in places I had not previously explored?  Thanks!

Comment: Please give your question a descriptive title.

Answer (score 23):

Carrots and potatoes can only be reliably found in villages, and they must be generated after the crops were added into the game.

However, they are also a rare drop from zombies, and while it's not the fastest way to get the items, it will save you quite a bit of walking.

Comment: Zombies is the answer here: my first find of each was from rare drops (I got lucky: first zombie kill after updating got be a potato!).

Answer (score 5):

You can only find carrots and potatoes in a place where chunks have not loaded yet. If you have looked thousands of blocks, no carrots or potatoes will spawn there.

Carrots are also a rare drop from zombies and can be farmed normally.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to find potatoes and carrots is to defeat Zombies. They have a rare chance of dropping the new eats. You can also obtain them in newly generated villages, where they have a chance of spawning in place of wheat.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to get carrots and potatoes, but since your in an older world, the second way is modified a bit. Here's what they are:

1. Rare Drops from Zombies
2. In chunks that you haven't been in in the earlier verisons (before carrots and
   potatoes were added) there may be a village, which will have them.